# Apache BEAM pipeline fails when writing TF Records - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: tensorflow, apache-beam, tensorflow-transform

The issue started appearing over the weekend. For some reason, it feels to be a DataFlow issue.

Previously, I was able to execute the script and write TF records just fine. However, now, I am unable to initialize the computation graph to process the data.

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 1492, in <module>
    MyBeamClass()
  File "my_script.py", line 402, in __init__
    self.run()
  File "my_script.py", line 514, in run
    transform_fn_io.WriteTransformFn(path=self.JOB_DIR + '/transform/'))
  File "/anaconda3/envs/ml27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 426, in __exit__
    self.run().wait_until_finish()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/ml27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 1238, in wait_until_finish
    (self.state, getattr(self._runner, 'last_error_msg', None)), self)
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 176, in execute
    op.start()
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 531, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
    def start(self):
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 532, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 533, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
    super(DoOperation, self).start()
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 202, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.start
    def start(self):
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 206, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.start
    self.setup()
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 480, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.setup
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 485, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.setup
    pickler.loads(self.spec.serialized_fn))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 247, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 317, in loads
    return load(file, ignore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 305, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1232, in load_build
    for k, v in state.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I am using tensorflow==1.13.1 and tensorflow-transform==0.9.0 and apache_beam==2.7.0

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=self.pipe_opt) as p:
    with beam_impl.Context(temp_dir=self.google_cloud_options.temp_location):

         # rest of the script

         _ = (
                    transform_fn
                    | 'WriteTransformFn' >>
                    transform_fn_io.WriteTransformFn(path=self.JOB_DIR + '/transform/'))
```

Comment: Same problem, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error.

It seems to be triggered by a mismatch in the `tensorflow-transform` versions of your local (or master) machine and the workers one (specified in the setup.py file).

In my case I was running `tensorflow-transform==0.13` on my local machine whereas the workers were running `0.8`.

Downgrading the local version to `0.8` fixed the issue.